# protection from stack overflow in R with a lot of free RAM

Tags: r, memory-management, stack-overflow, ram

I apologize in advance since this post will not have any reproducible example.

I am using R x64 3.4.2 to run some cross-validated analyses on quite big matrices (number of columns ~ 80000, number of rows between 40 and 180). The analyses involve several features selection steps (performed with in-house functions or with functions from the `CORElearn`package, which is written in C++), as well as some clustering of the features and the fitting of a SVM model (by means of the package `RWeka`, that is written in Java).

I am working on a `DELL Precision T7910` machine, with 2 processors `Intel Xeon E5-2695 v3 2.30 GHz`, 192 Gb RAM and Windows 7 x64 operating system.

To speed up the running time of my analysis I thought to use the `doParallel` package in combination with `foreach`. I would set up the cluster as follow

```
cl <- makeCluster(number_of_cores, type='PSOCK')
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

with `number_of_cluster`set to various numbers between 2 and 10 (`detectCore()` tells me that I have 56 cores in total).

My problem is that even if only setting `number_of_cluster` to 2, I got a `protection from stack overflow`error message. The thing is that I monitor the RAM usage while the script is running and not even 20 Gb of my 192 Gb RAM are being used.

If I run the script in a sequential way it takes its sweet time (~ 3 hours with 42 rows and ~ 80000 columns), but it does run until the end.

I have tried (almost) every trick in the book for good memory management in R:

- I am loading and removing big variables as needed in order to reduce memory usage
- I am breaking down the steps with functions rather than scripting them directly, to take advantage of scoping
- I am calling `gc()`every time I delete a big object in order to prompt R to return memory to the operating system

But I am still unable to run the script in parallel.

Do someone have any suggestion about this ? Should I just give up and wait > 3 hours every time I run the analyses ? And more generally: how is it possible to have a stack overflow problem when having a lot of free RAM ?

**UPDATE**

I have now tried to "pseudo-parallelize" the work using the same machine: since I am running a 10-fold cross-validation scheme, I am opening 5 different instances of Rgui and running 2 folds in each instances. Proceeding in this way, everything run smoothly, and the process indeed take 10 times less than running it in a single instance of R. What makes me wonder is that if 10 instances of Rgui can run at the same time and get the job done, this means that the machine has the computational resources needed. Hence I can not really get my head around the fact that %dopar% with 10 clusters does not work.

Comment: Your estimate of how much RAM is really being used by the calculation may be skewed, because an algorithm whose inputs take `O(n)` space may in fact take `O(n^2)` space when it runs.  As a general comment, I would suggest trying to find a way to work with smaller datasets.  If you can't do that, then yes looking into running something in parallel across several nodes might be an option.

Comment: I may be wrong but what I see as a memory usage is not an estimate, but the actual usage, since I am monitoring it with the resource monitor in windows.

Comment: Then you are correct, but I still say try to pare down the size of your model if possible +1.

Comment: Prune down the model is indeed part of my task here, but I have to do it within the cross-validation loop. The point is that some of the functions that I use to reduce the number of features are really memory consuming (consider e.g. the relieff algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

The "protection stack overflow" means that you have run out of the "protection stack", that is too many pointers have been `PROTECT`ed but not (yet) `UNPROTECT`ed. This could be because of a bug or inefficiency in the code you are running (in native code of a package or in native code of R, but not a bug in R source code).

This problem has nothing to do with the amount of available memory on the heap, so calling `gc()` will have no impact, and it is not important how much physical memory the machine has. Please do not call `gc()` explicitly at all, even if there was a problem with the heap usage, it just makes the program run slower but does not help: if there is not enough heap space but it could be obtained by garbage collection, the garbage collector will run automatically. As the problem is the protection stack, neither restructuring the R code nor removing dead variables explicitly will help. In principle, structuring the code into (relatively small) functions is a good thing for maintainability/readability and it also indirectly reduces scope of variables, so removing variables explicitly should become unnecessary.

It might help to increase the pointer protection stack size, which can be done at R startup from the command line using `--max-ppsize`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (that helped me understand the problem a bit better). Note that I am already running R with the maximum `--max-ppsize` allowed. I am now focusing on "pseudo-parallelization" to solve this problem.

Comment: Then it is most likely a bug in some package. You might try narrowing it down by using fewer external code, e.g. use `clusterApply` from `parallel` instead of `doParallel`/`foreach`. Internally, `PSOCK` cluster will spawn multiple R instances, so in principle does something similar to what you are doing manually.